# How do you test a steroid app on an iphone device?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, steroids

I'm attempting to develop a [steroid](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids) enhanced phoneGap app for ios. According to this [AppGyver link](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/steroids_npm/using-cordova-cli/) an xcode project cannot be built from a steroid project. What is the prefered deployment method for testing steroid projects on an iphone device? Tho only way I've managed is to deploy is through the AppGyver Scanner app, which seem like a pretty clunky workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For local development, you should use the `$ steroids connect` command to run a local server and use AppGyver Scanner to connect to it; this lets you see changes you make to your HTML5 code without having to recompile the app. `$ steroids deploy` should only be used when you need to share your app with someone else. After you're happy with the app, the AppGyver [Build Service](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/cloud_services/ios-build-config/) lets you build an Ad Hoc IPA to test it out further.